# Embedding X11 Translucent windows

Tags: qt, qt4, x11

I am trying to to embed a QWebview from one process into another process's window.  I want the background of the containing window to show through the contained webview.

test.cpp:

```
#define EMBEDDING 1

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QX11EmbedWidget>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

#if EMBEDDING == 1

    QX11EmbedWidget *parent = new QX11EmbedWidget();

#else

    QWidget *parent = new QWidget();

#endif


    parent->show();

    QWebView *web = new QWebView(parent);

    parent->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    QWebPage *page = web->page();
    QPalette palette = page->palette();
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, Qt::transparent);
    page->setPalette(palette);


#if EMBEDDING == 1

    parent->embedInto(atoi(argv[1]));

#endif

    page->currentFrame()->documentElement().setInnerXml("text");

    web->show();
    parent->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

test2.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget *parent = new QWidget();

    parent->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");

    parent->show();
    parent->move(100,100);


    std::cout << "Winid: " << parent->winId() << "\n";

    return app.exec();
}
```

I built these on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 with the following commands:

```
gcc test.cpp -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/  -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/ -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit  -I/usr/include/qt4/ -lQtCore -lQtGui -lQtWebKit -o test.out
gcc test2.cpp -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/  -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/ -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit  -I/usr/include/qt4/ -lQtCore -lQtGui -lQtWebKit -o test2.out
```

to run the code, first do `./test2.out` it should output a window ID, then do `./test.out <winid>` where  is the window id that is from the test2.out output

If you don't have a compositing window manager running, you may have to start xcompmgr

Instead of getting the result that I want, I just get a black square where the background of the other application should show through....

To demonstrate that translucency works in non embedding situations, just set EMBEDDING to 0 test.cpp

Please let me know if I am missing something or if there is a workaround.

Thanks

PS. I don't really know C/C++, I just ported my PySide problem case over for the benefit of this post. However, I should be able to Port any C/C++ recommendations back to PySide

Comment: It has been suggested on the QT mailing list, that may be a compositing issue.  I have looked at the code for xcompmgr, and it seems to refuse to do composite rendering for windows that do not have the root window as a parent.  I also tried compiz, but I wasn't able to get it to do any compositing...

Comment: Normal compositing manager deal with top-level windows only. You need to do your own compositing.